# :bundleReleaseJsAndAssets ERROR in React Native 0.57.1

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My project uses react native version 0.57.1 . I cannot upgrade the version of react native to newer versions because of one library named react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer. When i am building the project, the project is failing to release the apk but when it debugging it is being build. The project is only available for android.

When releasing the apk it is giving me error as

`> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/0d/j3_gbcw90g91rth_wg55hmlm0000gn/T/metro-cache/02/3154c487e966a254c29e1d9457ab44ec57855038ebde7a743fe3e6fba3e197fa1b73aa'

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/0d/j3_gbcw90g91rth_wg55hmlm0000gn/T/metro-cache/02/3154c487e966a254c29e1d9457ab44ec57855038ebde7a743fe3e6fba3e197fa1b73aa'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1384:35)
at FileStore.set (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/pharmasolution/pharmasolution-reactnative/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/FileStore.js:43:8)
at Cache.set (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/pharmasolution/pharmasolution-reactnative/node_modules/metro-cache/src/Cache.js:96:31)
at /Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/pharmasolution/pharmasolution-reactnative/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:190:13
at Generator.next ()
at step (/Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/pharmasolution/pharmasolution-reactnative/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:11:657)
at /Users/niteshrajkhanal/Desktop/pharmasolution/pharmasolution-reactnative/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:11:817
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
  Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

  BUILD FAILED in 35s
  15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
  ✨  Done in 39.71s.`

It is supposed to be built in both debugging and release. But it is failing to build while in release.

Steps that i have followed to release the apk are:

//To make APK file
//1.Delete (index.android.bundle) files inside directory android/app/src/main/assets.
//2.run $ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
//3.Delete folders (drawable,drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi,raw)
//4.run $ react-native run-android --variant=release